# Can I work around that substitutions are limited to 10000 bytes per personalization block in SendGrid?

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I'm trying to send an email with SendGrid using a transaction template. It is an order confirmation to a customer where I would like to show some basic information about the order together with a list of ordered articles.

Since SendGrid does not support sending in arrays of items and use them in transactional templates, I will have to translate them to HTML in my app and provide the full HTML in the substitution for {{articles}}

This works fine, until a customer decides to order a whole bunch of articles, (like 30+ or so depending on the style for each row) then I get this error message:

> substitutions are limited to 10000 bytes per personalization block

Anyone know of a good work around for this? Or should I simply use another email service (such as mailjet)?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th>Ordernumber:</th>
                  <td>{ordernumber}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Purchase identifier:</th>
                  <td>{purchaseidentifier}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Description</th>
                  <th>Quantity</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <!--{{articles}}-->
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

UPDATE Oct 2017:
There is a thread on Github that states this feature is coming soon to the SendGrid API. https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/221

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only sending a single email to a single user, could you populate everything out in your email body before handing it off to SendGrid, instead of using the substitutions?

Comment: Yes, we could do that, but I thought we do miss a bit of the nice features of even using SendGrid. It might end up with us downloading the template through their API:s and replace the whole HTML doc

Comment: you're missing out on substitutions, and possible transactional templates if you're leveraging those. You still get click&open engagement tracking, custom_args and the event webhook, suppression management, and the general delivery benefit however.

Comment: Yes, we solved it by downloading the transactional template from Sendgrid, replace the substitutions ourselves and send it with sendgrid. Downside is a more complicated solution and 2 http req per email, but upside - it works! Mailjet was the only service I saw that had solved this in a good way, where you could send in arrays of substitutions.